# Does anyone know what frame my bike is pls?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Hi need help finding out what frame my BMX is. Serial number is YSEL11E1518 under next to serial number says made in Taiwan ). Wheels are from a different bike I think pls help ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post images of the entire frame as well

Comment: Won’t let me put picture of frame

Comment: edit your original question and add the image

Comment: Do u have messager I’ll send u better pic m8

Comment: This question is basically unanswerable as it is. There are many, many BMX frames made in Taiwan and no database of serial numbers. If there is something unusual about the bike like a head badge or unusual construction, that could possibly lead to identification.

Comment: I think new users can only put two images in a post. Luke, if you put a link in a comment, somebody will edit it into your question. However, it's very unlikely that your question is answerable. A bike's serial number is only useful if you already know the manufacturer: they're not globally unique like cars. And looots of stuff is made in Taiwan. Finally, do you really need to know the manufacturer? if you just want to do up the bike, use whatever components fit.

Comment: @LukeNeedham Looks like a generic Freestyle Frame. The seatpost clamp, break cable guides and lack of reinforcements, give it away. I'm going on a limb here but, looks like Hiten steel and not Chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 3):

The frame is a lovely purple BMX frame.

Judging from your photos it seems in a very good state with no dents or bending noticeable. From the looks of it, it accepts fairly standard BMX components.

To find out if it is worth anything, ensure the completeness and safety of the bike and go ride it.

Comment: Surprisingly it has both wheels which is relatively unusual for these questions.   It looks almost complete, except that someone has removed the back brake, which is a bad idea.

Comment: I'll also note that the seat post is too short and is bending the seat tube at the top.

Answer (score -1):

Clean beside you sproket my stolen casino has its named stamped there opposite of the serial number

Comment: Cassettes, freewheels and chainrings are all wear-items and are consumables.  The frame serial number will be on the frame, not a sprocket.   OP has posted that their serial number is under the BB, as per the first picture.  He's looking for an identification.

Comment: I meant beside the sproket on the bb. My stolen has casino stamped in it on the left side while the right sidw has the serial number

Comment: Also he could look at his drop outs sometimes they stamp a marker there stolen, shadow conspiracy, and volume to name a couple