# Looking for help identifying my newest addition

Tags: identify-this-bike

Looking for info. All I can find on Google is a pic that matches but no information. Its apparently a Cycle Rite Dilecta made in Austria single speed with coaster brake.

Looking for some information on this bike. It has cycle rite as the badge its a single gear with coaster brake. It either say Dilecta, or Oilecta on the side. Has made in Austria on it as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is/52065#52065)

Comment: Oh, come on. If you want people to identify your bike, at least give us a photo of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

From your photo we can see its a blue diamond frame bike, with a single front chainring.

The tube's thickness suggest its a steel frame; you can test this with a magnet.

The chain appears to be rusty, and that is possibly exacerbated by Canada's roads being salted in the winter.  A salty road is hard on steel so they rust quicker.

The heatset appears to be a threadded one, again showing rust.

Your bike seems to lack a front brake, because there is no brake track visible on the front wheel.  Instead there is a continuous rust on the steel rim.

The tyres look tired -the white marks suggest they're older, as does the visible tread pattern.

Sadly your photo has missed out over half the bike, so we can't see any cranks, gearing, bars, brakes, saddle or hubs.

My guess is 80's but could be 10 years either side.

---

EDIT now I see that the bike has cottered cranks and a highly raked fork, puts this bike solidly into the 70s.