# Trying to figure out the brand of full suspension mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

[image]
The serial number is GS160450599
I won it in an auction. Its not stolen, checked the database already. But there is ZERO markings on it other than the serial. It seems to have heavy duty welds, and looks like it's built for punishment. Not sure if the wheels are originals.

Does it look familiar to any of you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: I think you have a broken spoke in your front wheel.

Comment: I have to ask this, if you don't know what it is, why did you buy it? I hope it didn't cost you very much.

Comment: Nice example of shark's teeth in the visible part of the front chainring.

Comment: @mattnz Since the bike has actually been identified, I don't think there's much value in closing.

Comment: @David - Do note my vote came in hours before the Q was answered, I  stand by it.

Answer (score 7):

It looks a lot like this [Walmart Genesis V2900](https://www.walmart.com/ip/29-Genesis-V2900-Full-Suspension-Men-s-Mountain-Bike-Blue-White/22899842) bike with the decals removed.

[image]

Comment: Awesome spotting - well done!   At $149 USD its totally a BSO (ie, a bottom-entry bike)  And some of the reviews are scary, like "frame failure after 18 months"

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a generic BSO dating from the 2000s.

Full suspension bikes basically require disk brakes.  V Brakes as your bike has are a sign of a low price bike.  That's not necessarily a bad thing.  I see plastic brake levers on the bars, which are a positive sign of a cheap bike.

The front fork stanchions do not have boots, which would have dated it earlier than 2000.

The wheel size looks bigger than 26" too - is it 27.5" or 29" ?  This could push the effective date back to the early 2010s if so.

Your observation of "heavy duty welds" also supports the low price point of this bike.  An expensive bike tends to have nice welds, not big chunky ones.   Bigger welds are required because the tube wall is thicker, because it is steel.

So while it could be a good bike to ride once you do some work, it is just a hack bike.  I'd expect the suspension to have lost some flex with age too, with a worst case of freezing up completely.

Good work for keeping it out of the waste stream though - a bike in a skip is a sad sight.

Comment: V brakes were invented for suspension bikes.

Comment: Correct, a 90s bike with V brakes could be nice.  A 200x or later bike with V brakes won't be as nice because discs pushed V brakes to the lower end then down to the BSO market pretty quick.

Comment: The welds on that frame look like the ones you see on aluminium, to me. (And don't steel tubes have thinner walls? Aluminium is lighter but weaker so you make a bigger, thicker tube to get the strength and the lower density means it's still lighter.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I also kept searching google for certain keywords, and I cam across Gravity, which I learned is a generic name stamped on many Chinese bikes shipped to many department stores. I would actually never buy this bike, I bought a lot at an auction and couldn't place this one. some aspects are heavy duty, and then there are very cheap items on it. thnx for the help.