# Find my frame game :)

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

I need a little help to find out what brand this frame is.
Components info:

- Complete Shimano Dura-ace black first gen (GA-200) except front and
  rear hub from Campagnolo.
- Wheels are old Weinmanns.
- Seat post from Selle Italia.
- Handlebar from 3T cycling.

Other relevant info:

- The original colour is a sort of metal red (dark). It is apparent on
  some pictures below.
- I found two engraved numbers on the frame that
  don't look like any other serial number I've seen before. One at the
  top of the seat tube (323) and one under the bottom bracket shell
  (Z100).

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!!

Pictures here:

https://ibb.co/ghjg3S (the full frame)
https://ibb.co/cXqhA7 (seat tube)
https://ibb.co/kJtfxn (bottom bracket shell)
https://ibb.co/b46Hcn (down tube)
https://ibb.co/fuRiHn (bottom bracket cable guides)
https://ibb.co/gzFccn (lug, seat tube-top tube)
https://ibb.co/csU3Hn (rear derailleur)
https://ibb.co/hRug3S (front derailleur and crankset)

Comment: The derailleur is late 1970s. The style of the frame as well. Minor detail: rear quick-release lever at the wrong side, points to a person not instructed in the correct use, if you got it second hand . So, clean the bicycle thoroughly, check, grease and adjust, change the cables (frayed RD cable) and enjoy the ride.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.vintage-trek.com/images/trek/TrekMidwest/TrekMidwest.pdf). The last page lists specs for all of the 1977 Trek bicycle models. The rear derailleur and wheels to match up with a TX700. (Some of the parts like the rear hub could have been swapped out over the years.) I also noticed the rear dropouts look the same as that era Trek bikes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Componentry and wheels aren't strong indicators, but the drop-out and distinctive lugs look _very_ similar to the bike pictured on the penultimate page of that PDF.