# I have a bmx I can't figure out with a stamp of ia* on bottom side front of frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Ok I just aquired a bmx through trade with a stamp of ia* on bottom side of frame and a serial # of wtu208po15oh and a secondary # of 312962

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Is there a problem with riding it?  Or a problem with identifying its brand and age?

Comment: But what's your _question_?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. FYI this site is pretty bad at identifying bikes, and can almost never help with a BMX. In general serial numbers are useless as there are no records of number formats or ranges available.

Comment: You need to ask a question. Do you want to know the Brand and Model of the bike? If so, ask that after your description of the bike. Also, as @ArgentiApparatus states, serials alone won't help much. Try adding details like text of any stickers/decals on the bike, list of components if you can find them (e.g. brand of brakes, etc), and picture(s) of bike.

Answer (score 1):

The Serial number:

WTU is for Trek or one of the Trek brands, like Gary Fisher.

H at the end is for the year of frame manufacture, 2013.

This is a Danish VIN type serial number, Which Trek appears to have adopted.

Edit:  Try the brandname  Vise/MirraCo Edit  BMX