# Hi! Im looking to ID a rebuilt touring bike with serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike, touring

[image: serial number at base of post near front gears]

[image: side view of bike]

Just bouncing around the net looking for answers and I found this site. Hoping there are some die-hard bike historians among you :)

I bought this from a fellow who rebuilds and repairs bikes. He says it might be a Miyata but isn't sure. I have tried searching the serial number but no luck. If anyone has information or speculation as to the make/model/year of this bike, I am all ears! Thanks for reading :)

-Sarah from Montreal

Comment: Generally speaking, serial numbers are useless for determining the brand of the bike.

Comment: Appears to be a medium range bike built in the 80s or 90s.  Likely the bar has been replaced.

Comment: Gorgeous bike - not knowing the history won't detract from the pleasure of riding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Duplicate voters, please see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duplicate

Comment: @ojs We're overloading the word because SE only has so many options for close reasons.  Its not a duplicate in the sense of this question was asked before, but it is yet another "identify my bike" where 95% of the questions remain unanswered.   So don't get hung up on the wording, or it should be closed as "too broad" or "not enough info"

Comment: @sarah  the previous owner is your best place to try for further info.  Or ask him where he got it.  Or just ride it as is and enjoy the mystery.

Comment: @Criggie couldn't you just decide this is offtopic or something? Stackoverflow already has enough reputation as a hostile place without this stupidity.

Comment: @ojs Maybe we need another reason for closing - "identification is difficult"  but that said it just needs the right person to see the question, however many years that may take.   Closing as "off topic" is also confusing because its clearly "about a bicycle"     I suggest you post a question in meta rather than continuing here.  Its a good point, and #identify my bike is becoming more common.

Comment: Since this bike has been re-painted and parts have changed it's a matter of trying to identify the frame. Sometimes, frame makers have distinctive lug work that allow for identification. How the seat stays are attached to the seat tube, drop outs, lug shape and cut outs etc. Better pictures - close up shots - see [How do I ask a good bike ID question](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question)

Answer (score 3):

Sarah from Montreal,

I'm not sure if you still have this bike, but it looks to be a Norco Grand Touring. This is the only picture I could find online.

https://bikeindex.org/bikes/864351

David from Ottawa

Comment: Great find - welcome to the site.  Some further evidence to support this: A) Serial numbers very close together - probably made within a few days of each other. B) Norco serial numbers are known to use the DS (dodsun) format. C) The 'magnum gt' model features the same white detailing on the head tube.

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like Miyata. I would advise you to look not for a serial number but for types of models of different years of release. Probably it will be possible to identify your bike.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [2010 comment](http://thesekineproject.blogspot.com/p/sekine-bicycle-database.html?showComment=1403538933499#c2973321227636371204) on a thread at the [Sekine Bicycle Database](http://thesekineproject.blogspot.com/p/sekine-bicycle-database.html), the `DS80` indicates that the frame is from the Dodsun Bicycle and Machinery Manufacturing of Taiwan.

A comment on a thread at [OzBMX](http://www.ozbmx.com.au/profile/22133-roy-boy/?do=content&type=forums_topic_post&page=3) says:

> DS is Dodsun who made frames for many brands including Redline, Cycle Pro and Crossrider

A [Google image search](https://bit.ly/2HCz0RD) for Dodson touring bicycles shows the usual assortment of random frames.

Finally, a post on [Bike Forums](https://www.bikeforums.net/18241855-post4.html) is most informative:

> Based on the location of the serial number [bottom of seat tube], this will probably be a Dod Sun of Taiwan serial number.
>
> The first line of the serial number will 4 characters, widly spaced. The first two characters will be "D" and "S" for Dod Sun. The next character will be a number for the year of manufacture of the frame, probably "9", "0", or "1". The last character will be a number "0" or "1", the tens column of the number for the month that the frame was made.
>
> The ones column for the month is the first character of the second line. The rest of the characters are numbers.

Based on this information, which may or may not be accurate, your frame could be a Miyata built by Dodsun in Taiwan in June of 1988. Or, it could be something completely different.