# What's that frame ? I can't find anything about it anywhere

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image: I've got no idea what frame that is, or when it's been made. If anybody knows anything about it please let me know]
I've got no idea what frame that is, or when it's been made. If anybody knows anything about it please let me know

Comment: It's a bike frame. What do you want to know about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. FYI this site is pretty bad at identifying bikes. The general consensus is that if you know what the frame material and general construction is and what the components are, you pretty much know everything you need to know (hence the possible duplicate). Apologies for sarcastic comments but I think folks get tired of the constant stream of 'identify this bike' questions that turn up here.

Comment: It's kind of hard to say how old it might be.  It's not old enough to have a cottered crank, but old enough to have a quill-style headset.  The brakes are good quality but not distinctive from an age standpoint.  It's reasonably likely that the "brifters" are original, making the bike newer than about 1990.  I'd guess the bike was built some time in the 90s.  Overall, it looks like a good quality bike.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus we're not bad at identifying bikes - its a difficult problem.  Could be someone will come along in later years with exactly the right answer.  Short of actual facts, the best we can do is estimate a decade, and give reasons why.

Comment: Looks like a Teker pro team frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really care to know how expensive/good it is, it's clearly good enough for me. I was just mostly curious about the brand. From what I've read here and there, "Teker" was a Swiss brand that was making custom made bikes. Anyway, thanks for all the comments/answers, I appreciate it.

Comment: Friendly FYI: This site does not work like a discussion forum, this should have been posted as a comment on @Criggie's answer, not as a separate answer. This will likely be deleted.

Comment: Any bike is a good bike if it gets used.   Now ride it !

Answer (score 1):

"Teker" seems to be a name related to pants and motorbikes.  A good google search phrase would be "teker road bicycle -pants -motor"

I found two bikes with the same brand listed - the logo is identical too.

- https://www.pedalroom.com/bike/teker-pro-team-36400
- https://www.pedalroom.com/bike/teker-6800-36250

Both have shimano 600 series components, which were released in DuraAce in 1983 and discontinued in the early 90s.

Thing is, your bike looks newer than that - based on appearance I'd spec yours at late 90s through to early 2000s.

Not a good answer, but its a start.