# Help identifying an 80's Raleigh bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

[Imgur album link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBRdY.jpg) with captions for each image.

Shimano 600 groupset, 42 and 52 tooth up front, 2x6. Cinelli handlebars, Capagnolo downtube shifters, Mavic MA40 wheels, Shimano 600 brakes.

I was under the impression that it was a Road Ace or Competition 12, it seems to have a mish-mash of parts from the 80s Raleigh line. The cable guide under the bottom bracket is Raleigh branded too, no serial numbers anywhere. I took it to my LBS and the woman there pointed out the ornate looking lugs where the tubes of the frame attach rather than being just welds and I cannot find any info about this or which bikes had this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's a gorgeous bike right there.  You should totally do it up and ride it.  Or pass it on to someone else who will use it.

Comment: The bottle mounts are relatively uncommon on a bike of that vintage, as are the mix of campy and shimano.   I 100% believe that is a cassette and a freehub, not a freewheel, even though its only a 6 speed, the racer bikes had cassettes in that size.

Comment: FWIW, one place you might check for a serial number is on the steerer tube. This is a bit of a pain, since you need to remove the fork to get at it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: FYI Shimano Dura Ace 600 came out in 1983 and it was available to the early 1990s1

Comment: @AdamRice is it a serial number for the frame or for the fork ?

Comment: @Ross this question is well illustrated, and OP stands some chance of getting useful results eventually.  IE, this is more likely to be answered than the "ID my BMX" questions.

Comment: @Criggie I’ve got a different British bike that only had a SN on the steerer, so “both”.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like one of the better Raleigh bikes from maybe the 80's.
The component group on it is not likely to be original at all, I would guess it was Campy, and someone "upgraded" to Shimano.

A note, there is no "correct" way, I am sure I'll be told, but on the rear wheel, having the skewer lever on the derailleur/hanger side would be something I would avoid.  I would recommend it go on the other side, and either "point" back or down.  ( many like to put it next to the seat stay, but I find it troublesome to use there, esp when it is cold and raining and such, unobstructed access is good ).

Comment: Some people prefer to put the QR lever on the derailleur side on disc-braked bikes, for what it's worth. (Not relevant in this case, of course.)