# What make and model?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have scoured the internet until I can't take it anymore. I just can't find out what make and model bike I have. I got the bike second hand and it had been repainted and had no decals or badges on it. I have put security tagging stickers on it and want to register it but need to know the make and model. The guy I got it from said he had for a few years and could not remember anything about it. Strange I know but after checking the frame number on-line I am pretty sure it's not stolen.

This is it.

[image: bike]

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone will be able to identify it, though the frame does look somewhat distinctive, which probably gives you a better chance than most of the similar questions we get here. Can you not give the make and model as "unknown"?

Comment: I have tried that but it bounced

Comment: Presumably you don't have to use correct values. How about  manufacturer: China, model: Hybrid?

Comment: A classic no-name BSO with front V-brake and rear disk mix, cheapish saddle and  'candle' post, old-style headset, cable-ties for the housings and no-name drivetrain.

Comment: Looks like a fine riding bike - you'll enjoy riding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: @RoboKaren I agree in principle but the asker here has stated a reason why they _do_ need to know the make and model.

Comment: Manufacturer: “Chinese” and Make: “BSO” is the answer for security registration. The reason the make:model is asked is so that if the bike is found, a quick search can be done for “White/Trek/Modelname” but if the police officer can’t determine the make/model then they go only by the serial number. So entering a make / model doesn’t help. I’ll add an answer to that effect on the “why should I care” question.

Answer (score 3):

The bike appears to be a low cost mass-manufactured bike sometimes termed a bike-shaped-object (BSO).

Identifying features:

- rear wheel appears to have single wall steel rim.
- stamped steel derailleurs
- stamped, riveted chainrings with integral plastic protector
- oversized, 'looks cool' frame tubes, mig welds indicate thick wall metal
- non-adjustable shock absorber fork
- lawyer tabs on front wheel
- integral quill stem
- low cost grip shifters
- all of those reflectors

The front wheel looks like it may be double wall aluminum, it doesn't have the obligatory wheel reflector found on big box store bikes.

Pacific Cycles is a likely source, they make bikes under about 20 nameplates, including Roadmaster, Mongoose, and Schwinn. They also make short lived 'custom' brands; for a while they were offering a GM branded series at Wal-Mart. Finding an exact year and model name may be difficult because components would be shared between different name plates.

It looks like it's been well cared for, and if it's working for your riding habits you shouldn't have any trouble finding spare parts, especially if you've got a community bike shop around. Any big box store bike could be used to scavenge parts to replace those on this one. You could upgrade some components as they fail, but the weight of the frame and some limiting factors like the head tube would prevent you from upgrading it one piece at a time to bike shop components.