# Free agent model?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]  need a little help to figure out the model and the year of this Free agent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: This one looks surprisingly close to complete - just needs a chain and brakepads, from that photo.  You could be riding this for cheap.

Comment: Thanks for your time and info this bike has been out in one of our barns in north Dakota for years was my brothers. Came across all of our bikes out there one day a skyway,hutch,GT,and my old PK ripper (my favorite) all in not to bad shape. Gonna be fun gettin em rollin again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because model identity requires specific kno ledge of far too much about the bike to be accurate from a photo.

Comment: What size chain do I need? Or do I buy one length and fit myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a Free Agent Limo 24 BMX" bike, circa late 80s to early 90s. [Here's a BMX museum page](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/free_agent/9970) with very similar looking one.

To find the model, I just typed "free agent 24" into Google image search and the second result matched the bike.

Comment: I like how you shared your research method as well as giving the answer.