# help me identify this kids bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]I would much appreciate it if someone could help me identify this bike?

i went ahead and did the measurements asked as well as took a photo for scale. the folding bike infront of a 29" mountain bike tire[image]

tyre reads 12x38
from ground level to the topside center is 21in
from the rear axle to the pedal gear axle is 9.5inches 
distance between the two wheel axles is 23.5in

Comment: I think what you've got there is not a kids bike, but a (maybe 1960's) adult folding bike that someone put a ridiculous saddle & handlebars on. Most of these "identify this bike" questions do not get very far on this site, but there may be a chance for this one. More close up pictures of the frame hinge, front fork, rear drop-outs & drive train would help.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a folder, and could very well have begun life as an "adult" bike, as many adult folders look like kids' bikes.  The details of the crank may give some clues, if you could get some closeups.

Comment: it's at a friends for the evening while i work. I'll get some more posted by tomorrow morning

Comment: What's the wheel size?  Read off the tyre ETRTO size if it has one.   I'm lacking a sense of scale cos your drawers could be any size.  It looks quite small.  Please also measure some dimensions - like wheelbase (distance between front and rear axle when steering is straight ahead) and height of saddle above ground.  The length of the pedal crank too - might be written on it or otherwise measure from middle of BB axle out to the middle of the pedal axle.   Use the EDIT link under your question to add further information.

Comment: @renesis folding kids bikes are not impossible.  I have worked on two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: With the added photo for scale, I take back what I said. It is not an adult bike...

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like this Bianchi / Nealeco
[image]
[image]

> Apparently this style folding frame was quite popular in Europe during the 1970s - many small boutique bike companies imported them [from Yugoslavia?], slapped their own identifying marks (decals) on them and sold them to their urban, and urbane, clientele. At least that is what I have read about them.
> [CLR Effect](https://centerlinerule.blogspot.com/2014/04/week-ending-c-v-little-bianchi-folder.html)

Here's a 12 inch wheel version in not quite Bianchi green
The chain stays and rear dropouts are a little different
[image]

It also looks like this Chiorda Safari
[image]
[Slender Fungus Cycling Association](http://ari-fixed-gear-pages.blogspot.com/2007/12/chiorda-folding-bike.html)

> The brand is Chiorda and it is a old italian bike. They made a high end road bike ridden by the famous Felice Gimondi. The company was later bought out by Bianchi who also bought out the Famous Legnano.

It looks like there were various wheel sizes with various brand stickers on this bike over the years.

Comment: The bike in the OP's photo has the hinge farther forward, and the cranks and fork are different.  Of course, the OP's is probably a lot older.

Comment: Nice finds - the nearest we're going to get, suggests its a kids bike from the 1970s, and possibly European.  These styles weren't seen in the US nor in Asia.