# What frame is 20" bike

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image: logo]  It's the frame from a box bike stamped where the rear wheel goes on I don't know the logo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to a Dave Moulton logo in design **but isn't**.

[image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8VhCxvEfbgTZoap0LUj_1ukKrEJGP5ZmFjuiwO5v3Z-3-wrqm6Q]