# I need to identify what kind of bike I have

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image: Close-up of the logo on the lug at the front of the top tube. The logo is a stylized "M" formed of three strokes, with a five- pointed star partially inset in the trailing stroke.]

[image: Slightly wider view of the logo, showing part of the stem, head tube and down tube.]

[image: View of the front triangle of the bike, upside down, from the non-drive side. Part of the fork and front wheel are visible.]

I need to find out what kind of bike I have. I just got it, it seems nice; I just need to know what it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Why doesn't anybody ask before they buy / steal / whatever?

Comment: @ojs + acquire / receive / upgrade-to / inherit / discover

Comment: Its a black BMX bike, with a high spoke count front wheel.  The factory brakes have been removed by someone.  The small chainring suggests its from this century, not last.   Enjoy getting out on your new bike!

Comment: Retracting VTC because an answer has been found.   Terry, feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" if it fits with your bike.

Answer (score 10):

The logo is that of [Mirraco BMX](http://bmx.wikia.com/wiki/Mirraco), which was started in 2006 by the late [Dave Mirra](http://davemirra.com/). Mirraco [got out of the BMX business](http://thecomeup.com/news/mirraco-drops-out-of-2014/) in late 2013 or 2014. You might be able to match up your bike with some of these on [RBikes](https://www.rbikes.com/articles/mirraco-bmx-bikes-pg899.htm).

[image: Logo from first link]

Comment: Stunning work - thank you.  Normally these questions go unanswered, this is the rare exception.  I've linked to the logo from your first URL, just in case the link goes stale in the future.