# Can anyone identify which Specialized Diverge model this is? It was built in 2017

Tags: specialized-bikes

I I am thinking about buying this bike, but the owner has no information about it. No specification sheet. Can anybody identify which bike model this is?[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ask how the seller ended up having the bike in the first place?

Comment: Yes,  he said he has used it in 4 triathlons.  I am VERY concerned that it is not stolen, but he listed it in Mercado Libre (sort of a Mexican EBay).  If a bike of mine like this had been stolen, this is one of the very first places I would start looking.  This is a very popular site, so I feel comfortable that it is not stolen.

Comment: Do you have photos from the actual events? That is not exactly a triathlon bike. And, how did the seller get it?

Comment: Does Mexico have a stolen bike database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: American Ebay and craigslist and what not likely have tons of stolen bikes; even if it is stolen, it's nontrivial to recover. A 1 or 2 year old bike that the owner doesn't know when it was made is suspicious.

Comment: The bike is almost brand new. Any legitimate owner should be able to give full details of such a new bike.

Answer (score 1):

That's a 2016 bike I think. The 2017 models did not have the kink in the seat stays.

I'm guessing it's above the 'Sport' Level (equipped with Sora), and below the 'Comp' (105).

I'd ask the seller if they bought it new and if so if they have a receipt.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a [2015 Specialized Diverge Elite A1](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=3055906) 
[image: 2015 diverge]

The bluebook link above gives some suggested market prices for the US, your mileage may vary.

It’s the lower end aluminum frame with a Tiara drivetrain. There is one more aluminum frame type (DSW) and carbon models above this one.

The lower end aluminum models lack the 
 “zert” inserts in the frame (the marketing at the time loved to brag about all the amazing “compliance” provided by the gimmick) and the fork was missing the mid-fork eyelets so you cannot mount a front low rider rack like the DWS and carbon frames can. Tire clearance was also slightly less and geometry slightly different on the lower end models.