# Help identifying a bike model

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can anyone help identify this bike ?

It is a Vivente bike but I cant figure out the model.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Now that this has been answered fairly well, I suppose we shouldn't close it.

Comment: Did you consider peeling off the sticker/transfer?  It probably only says Vivente underneath though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Vivente Como road bike circa 2007-2010 (judging by discussion forum posts and ad listings), converted to flat bars and some stickers/paint removed from frame. The crankset looks like FC-3550, which might be aftermarket too, since it seems to have been released somewhere 2013, several years after Como estimated production years (or maybe bike shop sold an old frame like that, who knows). [Vivente website](https://viventebikes.com/recent-models) does not list this bike as a previous model, but then again the list goes from 2018 to 2012. If you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1853&bih=1018&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=eyz6W6D0EsONsgGfm4XoAQ&q=%22vivente%20como%22%20bike&oq=%22vivente%20como%22%20bike&gs_l=img.3..0i24.128613.128987..129179...0.0..0.110.433.0j4......1....1..gws-wiz-img._lODkpxY32Q#imgrc=ktE7EFpQgzFxoM:) for images, [there](https://www.gear360.com.au/ads/vivente-como/) [are](http://www.bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?p=107059#p107059) [bikes](https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/z/DSMAAOSw~QRaQFfq/$_58.PNG) called "Vivente Como" with partially matching paint job (see bottom tube), fork and logo on it and RD hanger.

Comment: Thanks, definitely looks like the one. The flat bars really threw me