# Identifying a brazed steel frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, steel

I'm trying to identify this brazed steel frame I came across. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Lugged steel is pretty much passe these days, except perhaps for small shops (and the serial number does not suggest a small shop).  The cable guide is a fairly recent design, though, and there are no shifter bosses on the downtube, so the frame is not THAT old -- maybe ca 2000.

Comment: Thank you at least now I know it's called a lug steel frame.  Lol

Comment: What's the rear hub spacing? It has tendency to get wider, which is helpful to ballpark the age.

Comment: Stamped lugs for the most part indicate 70s-80s other than in certain markets where they persisted longer. Stamped fork dropouts with retention washer slots indicate a western dept store bike. The bilaminate headtube is fairly uncommon, not exotic by any means, but is kind of the main distinctive thing going on here and may be of help with the ID.

Comment: @DanielRHicks there aren't any cable stops on the frame either, which points to either clamp on cable hardware or coaster brake singlespeed. The dropouts could also be for either of these. The cable guide doesn't really fit and may be a later addition. Most frames have a drain hole at the bottom bracket and the screw looks like someone has tried to screw it into the unthreaded hole.

Comment: The crank/chainring looks too new for the bike.  The rear mech hanger is missing but would be a generic claw clamp, says 80s.    Fork shows a more modern profile on the tines, 2000's.  Chainstay has a clearance for the chainrings, 2000s.  Tyres are quite wide suggesting frame has lots of clearance.  Top headset bearing looks really odd in photo.    Rear wheel doesn't seem to have a brake track - its not suitable for that bike.   Summary - I think its a mongrel bitser made from misc parts, and a 1990s/2000s frame with a 2000's fork.

Comment: Your other bike in the background is a Mongoose BMX from the late 90s.

Comment: @Criggie the crushed chainstay thing has been done at least since 70s. There is nothing modern in the fork either. The thing on top of headset is mount for a bell. The rear wheel looks like it doesn't have a brake track because it has been clumsily spray painted, check the spokes. Everything matches to a coaster brake cruiser, except that the chainstays are too short.

Comment: @Criggie the other bike in background is badged as a schwinn with aluminum frame. I didn't think this bike was as interesting.  That's why i didnt ask about it.

Comment: @Flewthecoupe whoops!  you're right, apologies but it looked like https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rIAAAOSwHn9blr~V/s-l300.jpg     Search this site for the Schwinn serial number decoder link.

Comment: @Klaster_1. Looks just about 5" without pulling rim.

Comment: The other bike hasa nishiki seat on it that may be from this bike??? They where both found together