# What model of wethepeople bmx bike is this? HBOAG75989

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Can someone please tell me which type of wethepeople bmx bike this is?

Serial Number HBOAG75989

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: You might start by registering the bike to yourself at http://wethepeoplebmx.de/register-your-bike/

Comment: What evidence do you have that the brand is correct?  I see no decals or anything.  WTP bikes seem to have a lot more numbers stamped on the frame than you have quoted.

Comment: It's a model indistinguishable from dozens of other brands out there.  The only thing that might be distinctive that I see in the photo is the shape of the lug on the headset.

Comment: It has the wtp logo in quite a few different places. I tried looking at all the different brand descriptions and matching the parts that are on the bike but it matched a couple different types, I have the serial number

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an early WTP Omen or 4 Seasons based on the gussets and the style of the frame 2000-2005.

Comment: Welcome to SE and thank you for your input.  Would you be able to provide further info?  Specifically which gussets are you referring to - all I can see is a reinforcement lug aft of the head tube.   Adding another photo of the bikes you're referring to can help too.   These kinds of ID questions tend to be very hard to answer, so great work for providing something to go on.

Comment: I contacted WTP with the serial number. We shall see what they say.