# Who made this bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I can't find a manufacturer anywhere on the web[image]

Comment: Can you add more photos?

Comment: Serial numbers in bicycles are manufacturer-specific and generally useful only if you already know the manufacturer, and they either have a known formula for the number or have kept records and are willing help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information in the picture to give any real answer.

However we can tell its an ashtabula, or one-piece crank.  This is a sign of a low-end bike, or possibly an old one (ie 1960s or earlier.)  Modern bikes use a 3 piece crankset where the crank arms are bolted to a spindle.

The paint looks good in the photo, without wear and tear.  And the stamped serial number is regular and lined up, not the slightly ragged result of a hand-punched number done one digit at a time.

Upshot - cheap nasty BSO bike made in China or some other Asian country.