# What is the brand/model of my bike frame?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Does anyone know what brand/model is bike from photos or serial number?
[image: old road bike]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: It's old.  Probably built prior to 1970.  Pretty good quality for the time.  But there aren't really any distinguishing features to nail down the brand/model.

Comment: I'd say French, because of the MAFAC type centre pull brakes which were mostly used buy French builders.

Comment: I have a few photos. Someone has painted frame, don't have any stickers :(
https://app.box.com/s/h4ot59qx6zgj84u05k5mc8jdwocue6nf

Comment: @SaSaDuric that side-photo of the front fork - I'm not sure if the fork tines/legs are bent backward or if its just an aberration of the photograph.  Do check before riding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a 1970s steel framed road bike of decent quality.

It has cottered cranks which went away before the 80s, and it has quality centerpull brakes.

**I can't guess the maker**, but it smells like a European bike to me.  The Woods valves may imply Dutch or English or Japanese, but its just as likely to have had other tubes fitted over time.

There are some brake bits and gear shifters missing and parts that need replacement like tyres and tubes, brake pads and probably chain.  However its 97% there and could be easy to get going again.  Main gotcha is the condition of wear parts like headset and wheel bearings and BB races.

The side photos show a fork with comparatively little rake on it compared to the era.  So this bike would have felt lively and easy to turn.  That reactivity would be valued in a race situation, but less so on a commute or long-distance bike.

Note the quill stem seems to be raised up a lot - Do check the minimum insert line is down and not visible.

Totally loverly bike.  You could do a bare-minimum fixup and ride it, or you could do a full-on restoration with re-chroming and everything.  Whether you stay with 27" wheels or go for the slightly more modern 700c wheels will depend on whether the brakes will reach a 700c rim - you need 4-6mm more reach on the brakes.  Or possibly change brakes for long-reach dual pivots like Tektro 559.