# I need some help identifying a bike I just acquired

Tags: repair, identify-this-bike

I need help identifying this bike.

[image: bso]

Comment: Know what its worth... ballpark?

Comment: Valuations are off-topic here. Providing a value is essentially impossible because they are very dependent on location and current used bike market conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Please mark Klaster's answer as "accepted" because its worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

The frame is Yeti A.R.C. 1992. [Source](https://www.yeticycles.com/tribe/archive). You can tell by distinct rear triangle tubing/dropout and top tube cable routing.

Comment: That is crazy how fast you answered that.  Ive been searching on my own for weeks. Thank you

Comment: @Adam So you, er, just "acquired" a bike but you don't know what it is and your only interest in it is selling it. That sounds reassuring.

Comment: Well, at least it's not a black BMX... I only had to look though "retro mtb" images query for a couple of minutes.

Comment: For true mystery bikes, the police is usually a good place to start.