# I'd like to know what kind of bmx bike I have

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

I got this frame in an old pile of junk ,can you please let me know what kind it it t/y

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Someone’s going to ask about those bolt cutters sooner or later

Comment: The chain is greased, tyres not flat. Quality Deanne with three-piece cranks. That must have been a pretty posh junk pile.

Comment: @swifty That's a >CUTTING< observation.....

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted.  That certainly doesn't appear to be a BSO from a big-box store.  It looks to be handmade, and the apparent lack of oxidation on what appears to be raw metal means that metal might be titanium.  Both the seat tube and the crankarms are almost certainly aluminum, and both of those appear to have normal aluminum surface oxidation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Maybe because people get suspicious when somebody claims to have found a decent-looking bike in good condition in an old pile of junk and there happens to be a pair of bolt-cutters in the photo?

Comment: @robert Do you intend on riding this bike?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an Auburn CR-20RX
 [image]
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/auburn_racing/7968

Page with a variety of builds over the years
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/auburn_racing/

Comment: That does look _very_ similar, but it doesn't have the gusset where the top- and down-tubes meet the head tube.

Comment: It looks like the aluminum version. They built versions of this frame for years. The second link has a long list with pictures.

Comment: I didn't see any with the gusset on the first page, but I didn't notice that there were multiple pages. I think it would be an improvement if you linked to one that actually has the gusset, rather than jsut claiming that there is one somewhere in those seven pages of photographs.

Comment: It appears to be a 1994 Auburn JR-20RX
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/auburn_racing/67331
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/auburn_racing/11076
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/auburn_racing/36235