# Can anyone help me with what kind of bike this is?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

This is definitely an old bike, lots of modern work done to it but has original frame. The serial code on it is just under the seat at the back of vertical part. It’s HBK 367 25PC. The front badge simply says ‘bsp made in holland’ And also on the front it says "hand made steel frame"

I’m looking to sell the bike and don’t want to get ripped off.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Its unclear to me what you are asking, It’s a bsp, it says so on the front, it was made in Holland. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Just generally info? Is it worth anything or is it in any way out of the ordinary! I want to sell the bike and don’t want to rip myself off

Comment: Please! Don't end every sentence with an exclamation mark!! It makes you sound like an excited puppy! Who's very excited!! About everything!!!! Oh my god, it's just so exciting!!!

Comment: @VincentBennett valuations are off topic on this site because they're localised, and dependent on availability and demand.  If you're in Holland you probably could give this away, maybe.   Its worth whatever some would pay for it - that being the definition of worth or value.

Comment: Why don't ask whoever you got it from?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search sends one to the Dutch bike manufacturer BSP: https://www.bsp-fietsen.nl

According to what the internet says it's a Dutch family company started in 1986. They build their bikes in the Netherlands, according to what their webpage says.

As it comes to the geometry of your bike it's the typical Dutch "oma fiets" - grandma bike. I wouldn't be surprised if the bottom bracket was a threadless press-in style.

Comment: Ok thank you, I was hoping there might be something about it that was unique but I guess not! Sorry for the unnecessary post! Thanks again for the answe

Comment: @VincentBennett in the land of the bike (Holland) there are millions of bikes like this.  Its still very nice and would be great for you to ride.

Comment: @VincentBennett There's almost never anything unique about a bike. Most of them are just generic, mass-produced commodity items that cost a couple of hundred dollars/euro/pounds new and are worth a small fraction of that second-hand.