# Dyno Mountain Bike?

Tags: mountain-bike

Did Dyno make Mountain Bikes? I always thought of this one as a MTB. Can anyone give me more information about it? It has this number on the bottom: 9552795 and 21 speeds with 26 inch tires. It's all original except the neck and bars. The original neck and bars are above it.
[image: Dyno MTB?]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for Glenn. A more specific question would help. Something like "Would this bike be good for [your type of riding here]?" or tell us about some kind of problem with the bike. Please don't ask us about value - we don't do estimates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Nice example of a late 1980's-early1990's MTB. In those days a MTB was 'A heavy road bike with 26" wheels and more gears"

Comment: This style was often called a "mountain bike", but relatively few of them ever made it out of town.  (That's a very creative bike stand, BTW.)

Comment: In the photo it looks like front quick release is open. It's probably best to check that it's used correctly.

Comment: And, evne if not open, badly installed. You should point the lever backwards so there's no chance of it snagging on something and yanking you off the bike.

Comment: Matt's right - its a standard early 90s MTB.   Back then could have been called an ATB for All Terrain Bike.  Dyno certainly did brand bikes, my kid has one.  Cantilever brakes look fine, its not dirty or rusted.  In fact it is suspiciously clean!  I'd refit the front wheel, sort the brakes which look slack, and flatten the saddle.  If you want to keep it long term, perhaps touch up the red paint where its chipped on the top tube and the chainstay.   Super-nice bike!

Comment: This is Glenn and I'm sure I'm doing this wrong but I want to thank all who commented on my question. Special thanks to mattnz and Criggie for elaborating further. It's my bike, bought it in college but forgot exactly when (worked full-time to pay for school and it took me 10 years to get my engineering degree). I don't drive anymore so I am now overhauling the whole thing so I can ride it again but needed to know age for parts. Local bike shop said junk it as it is so old and 'used' but will never do that. It was being tinkered with in the photo but I corrected all the items mentioned. Tx agn

Comment: P.S. I think it's frame is cro-moly as it pinks sharply when struck by a metal object and no rust at all. I