# I have a bmx bike that i bought as a Subrosa but someone told me that it's an Eastern.I don't know what bike or frame it is

Tags: bmx

It was listed as a Subrosa.It had Subrosa stickers and the headset was turned around so the seller could put a Subrosa sticker on it.It has a seat that looks like it's Subrosa but underneath it says VELO.I don't know if that's real or not.I have the frame number,found it on the bottom bracket.I removed the stickers and turned the headset around.The frame number is TIR-0331.I want to know the brand,model,and year.
It won't let me put photos...

I removed the stickers, turned the headset around and added 4 pegs.

Comment: The serial number alone is no use at all: they're not guaranteed to be globally unique and there's no master database. If you'd already narrowed it down to a few possible manufacturers, a serial number might help, but that's all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: A high percentage of all saddles are made by VELO, so that’s not a problem, it’s probably a legit saddle. Can read more here: https://www.bikeradar.com/features/inside-velo-saddle-factory/

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for us to know if it's real or not based on the information provided. Having the number from the frame won't help.
VELO is the name of company that makes many types of seats for many kinds of bicycles. Having a Velo seat does not indicate if the bike is or is not really Subrosa.

Edit:
[Contact Subrosa](https://subrosabrand.com/contact-warranty/) with the number and see if they can match it to a bike they made.

Comment: Can you give me more information about it?