# How to verify bicycle by frame serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

[image][image]

I have a problem to verify the model of the bicycle.

I have frame number - A4D58277 but can't check anywhere in Google, by which company was made.

Comment: There is no universal registration of bike serial numbers.  Even the number stamped on the frame doesn't necessarily mean much.  Your best bet is to figure out the manufacture of the frame, and see if they have a lookup for it.  However, all of this is generally irrelevant, as who originally made a bike doesn't have any real bearing on its rideability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: This question shoud be closed and not set as duplicate.

Comment: A clear picture, straight-on of the bike from the chain side will really help. As will a closer picture of the markings on the down tube. Telling us which country this is in will also be useful.

Comment: Its almost impossible to identify a bike by serial number alone. To the people who ask why you would want to know? There are more reasons for wanting to know who made the frame you own than its "rideability" or initial cost. For example if like me you love your frame regardless of whether it's a comp mtb or a cheap Chinese copy or anywhere inbetween but don't know who made it, obviously makes parts difficult to source, although you can generally get round this with measurement. But you can't get around things like original paint or decals which are important if you are restoring or rebuilding.

Comment: @David Curiosity is always a valid reason. However, unless you are trying to restore a bike to original condition, it's much easier to figure out replacement parts by measuring than by figuring out what make the bike is and then also finding the specs of that bike in enough detail to know, e.g., what kind of bottom bracket it has: _both_ of those things tend to be very difficult.

Comment: @DavidRicherby agreed in every sense regarding parts it's a far simpler problem to get around measuring for correct sized parts than the minefield of attempting to identify a frame from little to no information but still doesn't get around the decal, paint code or colorway options if you are looking to restore or rebuild a unknown bicycle.

Comment: @David Agreed. That's why I explicitly said "unless you're trying to restore a bike to original condition".

Comment: @DavidRicherby You did. That's my bad, I read it too quickly. However  I do think there are still more valid reasons someone may want to know who manufacturered their frame other than generally curiosity or trying to re spec to original. Such as insuring  your beloved bike, talking about your bike with friends or maybe even selling it most people don't buy a bike for components alone so would want to know who made the frame. Or maybe even as a reference point on how much to spend on a rebuild as I know rideability and geometry are arguably more important than manufacturer   however nobody is..

Comment: ..going to spend hundreds on high end components for a department store frame  or vice versa you wouldn't want to rebuild a rare old handbuilt comp mtb with cheaply produced generic bearings or the like.

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus please check I add new pic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logo on the downtube shows some similarity to the logo on this bike: https://www.ccrracing.de/road-rahmen/13-ccr-attack-carbon-rahmen.html

I can’t find a similar looking model on that site but you could contact them at least to ask about the serial number. It seems like the best place to ask, in the first instance.

It looks to me like it’s a metal frame, road style, but current models on that site are all carbon and mostly TT frames. Could be relevant to the question, maybe it’s an older model, I don’t know the history of the company.

Googling CCR is hampered by a model of Fuji bikes with that name, the band Creedence Clearwater Revival and a model of Koenigsegg which all seem to be more famous.

We’re now looking at Quantec, so I’m parking this link here for posterity: http://www.quantec-bikes.de/page/road/race_sl.html

Answer (score 7):

Basically, the answer to the title question is "You can't." There's no global database and each manufacturer just uses whatever scheme they want. Unless you've already narrowed it down to a couple of candidate manufacturers, the serial number won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

@Swifty I have written a letter to  https: //www.ccrracing.de/road-rahmen/13-ccr-attack-carbon-rahmen.html but they didn't approve and said "Its looks like a quantec bike"

Comment: It shows some similarity to this one, in the head tube and cable stops particularly: http://www.quantec-bikes.de/page/road/race_sl.html the fork is different but given a respray seems likely, that could have been swapped out very easily. Worth emailing quantec with the serial number and photos

Comment: At least CCR were kind enough to reply so you know that it isn’t one of theirs

Comment: @Swifty I wrote to quantec and they answered me: "Hello, we do not registrate the serial numbers. Maybe we sold this frame! It seems to be the model Quantec Race SL - 95%"

Comment: That’s a pity but again it was kind of them to answer. I think there are strong similarities between them, 95% confidence from Quantec seems good!

Comment: @Swifty I agree with you that 95% almost match)