# Help please with this picture. Bmx frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image] any help please with this picture would great. Any info. Trying to find out the make off this bmx frame. The serie number is r87071855

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 3):

This frame can't be identified

Thousands of frames are mass produced in China every year that look just like this.
The same frame from the same factory may have different "brand" names attached to them.

Serial numbers cannot be used to identify a frame. There is no database to search and if there was different manufacturers could use the same number.

This frame has been stripped clean of all identifiable:

- parts,
- logos
- original paint

And, because the frame's basic design is so generic (no unique design, or identifying characteristics) it can't be identified (At least based on this picture. If there is something identifiable on this frame and you can post a picture of it we'd have a clue to run with)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Petsounds and if someone's telling you that its valuable, then they're very likely lying or have been misled themselves.