# Help identifying make of steel elevated chain stay mountain bike frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Could anyone tell me what is the make or model of this bike there are no visible numbers or name except for this sticker of the maker of the seat tube.

I appreciate all the help. you guys know your stuff.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It *is* a fairly unique design.  Unusual to see the angled chain (?) stays like that.

Comment: (It may have been designed to accommodate a belt drive without the need to have a joint in the stay.  I'm guessing it's an early belt drive bike.)

Comment: Would be helpful to have a closer shot of the right rear, to see what's hanging off there.

Comment: Here's a belt drive bike with a similar geometry (though obviously not the same manufacturer): https://ratrodbikes.com/forum/index.php?threads/belt-drive-huffy-venue.106072/

Comment: A little closer: http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=322281

Comment: I've seen something similar - was an early 90s MTB back when "rigid" was implicit.   Looks like a sweet frame - you should totally build it up and ride it.   That decal means the frame is built from "Reynods High Tensile Steel Tubes" which is a fairly good thing, it will be relatively light.

Comment: A lot of companies made elevated chain stay bikes in the early 90’s. Some more info here: https://forums.mtbr.com/vintage-retro-classic/elevated-chainstay-bike-history-questions-590280.html#post_6563770.   That bent seatpost on yours ought to help narrow down which brand it is, but I don’t know them well enough to guess what it is.

Comment: It was unrelated to belt drives.

Comment: Reynolds make the steel tubes but not the frame itself. It's weird that somebody seems to have taken the bike-maker's stickers off the frame but not the tube company's.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - It is possible that it's a custom frame -- an experimental model, perhaps.

Comment: @DanielRHicks True. But then it's weird that the builder felt the need to put a "Reynolds made these tubes" sticker on it, but not an "And I turned them into a bike" sticker.

Answer (score 8):

[image]Roadmaster Techno Trac.
Sears never made bikes, they bought them from other companies like Steyr, AMF-Roadmaster and Murray.

see one here with the original decals still intact (and a broken frame)
https://www.flickr.com/photos/rickpaulos/49958454372/

Comment: That's a dead-ringer.  Excellent find and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5):

Sears F.S. (Free Spirit) Elite.  Came in Teal or Blue.  Made out of high tensile steel.  So heavy it feels like it was made from lead and pig iron.  Came with cheap parts.  Made at a time when everyone and their brother was climbing aboard the e-stay bandwagon in the early nineties.  I've only seen a few of them, and all were 19" frames.  I have one in storage.

Comment: Based on Frank's information I was able to find pictures of bikes matching the frame in the original post. The fill name is F.S. Elite ESD 6000. Here's a link to pictures https://offerup.com/item/detail/690996686/

Comment: Fascinating bike. I never knew Reynolds put their name to "high-tensile" steel. It also looks from the pictures like it's been MIG welded.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in many threads on this site, (for example this one: [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)), it is rarely necessary to know the exact make and model of your bike, unless if happens to be something so special that it has high collector value.

Based on the frame material and design of your bike, it is clear that it is a decent, but fairly generic frame, so it is extremely unlikely to be of high value.

What might you need to know about this frame?

1) the material: Conveniently provided by the sticker.

2) what components will it take?

Based on the design, it was almost certainly produced between 1989 and about 1995 (when steel elevated chainstays frames were briefly popular and a ton of different companies made them). It's a mountain bike that is intended to take 26 in wheels and post-mounted brakes, such as cantilevers or v-brakes.

The bottom bracket shell is very likely to be a standard threaded, 68 mm wide. This will accept a wide variety of bottom brackets, so you can set it up with just about any type of crank you want.

The fork is threaded, so you will need to use a quill stem or a quill adaptor.

The rear dropouts are probably 130mm (this can easily be measured to check), so using modern 8-10 spd rear wheels (with 135 mm width) will require spreading them a bit. Older 7-speed rear wheels should fit.

If for some reason you still really want to know the exact make and model, you can sift through pictures online of this style of bike (search something like "90s elevated chainstay mountain bikes") and compare the frame designs. The bent seat tube is an easy to spot feature, as is the ovalization of the down tube where it meets the head tube. Also the U-shape of the chainstays and seatstays and the lack of any extra cross pieces in the rear triangle. Whether you find it is just a matter of luck, as so many different frames of this style were made that you'll only find images of a small fraction of them.

Answer (score 0):

ESD 6000 frame
The bikes were sold by Sears and a late '80s

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You can improve this answer by including an image of the bikes you're talking about, and a link if you can find one.

Comment: Also, there's one answer that covers this information.