# Can anyone give me some information on this Peugeot frame I bought this weekend?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, vintage, peugeot

I've been looking through old Peugeot brochures and searched the numbers on the frame but I cant find any pictures of any Peugeot bikes that look like this one. The chrome section with the flags of France bordering it the major differences. Peugeot bikes that I've seen usually have a checkered flag pattern where the French flag is here. In the Chrome section there is a long black and white arrow with another French flag in it. The guy I bought it from told me it was from the late 1970s. On the dropouts there is the number 85448 and on the bottom bracket shell is the number 57. From what I have read it's basically meaningless with how inconsistent Peugeot were with their numbering.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you've already talked to the best source of information, the previous owner.

Comment: I bought it at a flea market.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: I don’t see a question here.

Comment: The steep head tube angle compared to the seat tube angle might give you some hints.  Don't assume the paint is original.

Comment: With that steep head tube angle and that huge of a fork rake, if you build that bike up and ride it, it's going to be either really twitchy or downright unstable.  The steep head tube angle and the large fork rake mean that bike will have very little trail, or even negative trail.  Trail is the distance between the where the pivot axis of the front wheel intersects the ground and where the front tire actually touches the ground. Think of the front wheel of a shopping cart.  A large trail is more stable, and a negative trail (contact point ahead of the axis) may be impossible to ride.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  This has the typical pre-70s frame configuration. There's no reason why it should be unstable.I own a 1930s bike where the fork reaches even further forward.

Comment: It's a feature of old French bikes. Wide tires tame the behavior a bit.

Comment: I can't find what it is (suspect its a special edition).  But I did find a couple of websites with loads of old peugeot catalogues you could check:  http://www.peugeotshow.com/  and   https://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/index.html

Comment: Almost all serial numbers are completely meaningless. Anyway, what "information" are you looking for? It's a bike frame -- add wheels and stuff and ride it.

Comment: @Andrew Henle - 0 trail was the norm pre 1950's and many frame builders continued the tradition for a while. Heavier bikes, wider tires, longer wheel bases, and the poor conditions of roads they were riding on 'tamed' the twitchy behavior.

Answer (score 6):

I have a peugeot frame of a similar age and have found it to be more bother than its worth.

There was a period when peugeot made an effort to make all of their compenent dimensions round metric numbers. This practice was not adopted by many other manufacturers so getting parts to fit that frame might be a hassle.

On my peugeot frame;

Steering tube internal diameter is exactly 22mm, so standard quill stems (7/8 inch, approxmiately 22.2mm) will come frustratingly close to fitting, but wont in the end.

Pedal threads are 14mm (I think), again, frustratingly close to standard (9/16 Inch approximately 14.3mm) but incompatible.

Seat post diameter is 24mm which seems to be a defunct size, thankfully smaller diameters are available so shimming is an option.

Not sure about bottom bracket threads or anything else because I shelved the project

I sincerely hope that your frame is not of this era because they are really nice from my experience. A friend lent me an approximately late 70s/early 80s peugeot for a while and it really was very pleasant to ride.

You might find these links useful.

http://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/

https://www.sheldonbrown.com/velos.html