# Any idea what this is, seller says it's a Haro

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, bmx

This bmx is advertised as an old school Haro but I'm not so sure it is.

[image: white bmx orange wheels photograph from seller listing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Could be a Haro.  Definitely better quality than your standard dept store bike.

Comment: @DanielRHicks and surprisingly, a complete bike not a bare frame and it still has brakes.  I'd suspect the tyres/rims are original, as are colour-matched seatpost clamp and stem.  Not sure about saddle, might have expected an orange one, can't be sure.   I can't find a picture of a chainring with a H logo on it from anyone.   But it looks decent quality and easily rideable again.

Comment: @mattnz In this case, I think the asker should care, since it could significantly afffect the value of the bike they're considering buying. (Of course, we don't give advice on value, but that's not what's being asked.)