# I want the year and model of my powerlite BMX bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

This is my powerlite BMX bike. The serial number is ACC93J0783 I would like to know what year and model it is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Is there a particular part that you are trying to replace on your bike or is this just to satisfy your curiosity?  In the former case you should ask specifically about what you need, with more specific photos.  For a general ID question, you should review [how to ask](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337/43557) a good question, but note that [it may not really be important](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52060/43557).

Comment: @DavidW Done - SE automatically deals with linking to a higher res photo if its larger than the column width.

Comment: The year is sometime between about 1975 and 2019.

Answer (score 3):

I see a One-piece crank which suggests its a lower-end bike frame.

The lack of other parts suggest its not rideable in its current state.  You'll need wheels, saddle, chain, freewheel, brakes.

Upshot - Assemble it and ride it.  Doesn't matter what the decals said originally.