# Help identifying a vintage Diamondback full suspension MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, full-suspension, diamondback

Can anyone help me with identifying a vintage Diamondback full suspension MTB? I know there are a ton of similar requests, but I need parts and I am stuck without the correct model/year of this Diamondback frame.

Regards and thanks for any help offered

Peter

[image]

Comment: You generally don’t need to know the year and model to get parts. What are you trying to fix?

Comment: [This](https://www.mtbr.com/product/older-categories-bikes/2003-full-suspension/diamondback/coil.html) claims to be a 2003.

Comment: As far as part for repair - looking at the front forks and overall state of the bike it will probably be uneconomical to do more than get it rideable.   At a minimum it needs front brakes.

Comment: Possibly i'm being a bit of a bike snob, but i'd say every $/£/€ spent restoring this bike is a waste.  I can't think of any type of riding it is suitable for.  You'd get a much more capable bike by spending the restoration budget on an entry level modern bike from a reputable manufacturer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a late 90s BSO.

I also notice the boots/stanchions from the forks have rotted and dropped off.  And that you're missing the front brakes completely.

Not only that, the front rim is completely missing a rotor and doesn't even appear to have a rotor mount.   I suspect the front wheel was replaced at some point.  As such, this bike is not safe to ride.

The suspension is a spring with a damper on the inside.  The damper will be purely cosmetic and any damping capability will have long since vanished.  I found that a 60 kilo teenage rider could over-compress the rear suspension making the whole bike extremely saggy to ride.

That frame shares a lot with this late 90s Raleigh RFX

[image: Own work]

*UPSHOT*  If you have a disk front wheel, rotor, and spare working front caliper/lever already, it looks like a straight forward tune up.  If you have to buy any more than cleaner and lube then think twice.  Unless its sentimental in which case its your decision.