# Hi can anyone name this frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Hi, im looking to identify this frame f anyone can tell me???

Thank you if you know :)

Comment: That rear bracket thingie is a bit unusual.  Otherwise it's pretty generic.

Comment: I hereby name your bike "Kermit"  Now go buy a green saddle/cover and a green  chain.

Comment: I can't even see the bottom bracket being the disc chainring. The crank looks like basic Ashtabula to me.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Could be a GT Pro Performer from the 85/86 era, this looks similar https://www.pinterest.com/pin/453315518714605807/?nic=1

Comment: Seat post and crank has probably been changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: @danK You can check that somewhat with a reverse search - googling for "1986 GT pro performer BMX" returns that green one from pintrest with a hoopy thing below the saddle, but all the other results lack that.  I'd suspect pintreset to have misfiled the image ?
However the hoop and the kinked downtube could be enough for the Right Person to authoratively say what it is.   Also, https://zonessupernew.netlify.com/1986-gt-pro-performer-serial-numbers.html shows the under-saddle area, looks a lot different to OP's hoop.

Comment: The handle-like thing below the saddle does at least look somewhat distinctive.

Comment: Found the same image, where the bike is offered up to sale on this page [adverts.ie](https://www.adverts.ie/mountain-bikes/custom-built-bmx-skyways/18497207) >**Description** >Custom BMX, skyways, odyssey crank, kneesaver bars, all colour coded

Answer (score 5):

The best match I could find for the frame is a Falcon Pro Freestyler

[image]
The [bike in the picture is a 1996](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/falcon/58631).

From what I'm seeing in the [BMX Museum this frame was made between 1992 and 1996](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?q=&year-start=1967&year-end=2020&type%5B0%5D=3&wheelsize%5B0%5D=3&company%5B0%5D=491&sort=year&d=asc&pg=1). I was unable to find other information to confirm this observation.

Comment: I think we have a winner!