# BMX bike brand frame

Tags: frames, bmx

Can you help to tell me what this frame is[image]

Comment: That's the Specialized logo. More than that is impossible to tell from the photo.

Comment: You should check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52060/43557 since mostly it doesn't matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)