# Can anyone identify this green frame?

Tags: frames

Like many others, I found this aluminum frame bike that is pretty light and in great shape.  The bike has been converted to disc brakes and I believe that everything is aftermarket. 
Serial number reads PY4220305. A Threadless neck, and an extra plate welded under the neck.!
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you for your help!

Comment: How did you "find" a nice looking bike like this ?   I'd wonder if that downtube plate is original - the weld to the head tube looks the same above and below.   Also, its not been converted to disks, those disk mounts are integral to the frame and fork.  That it has V brake mounts suggest it was one frame for multiple tiers of model.   Nice and super-clean bike BTW.

Comment: Looks expensive for an abandoned bike. Probably best to check if it's been reported stolen.

Comment: I apologize if I led you believe it was abandoned,  as I paid for it through private sale. I don't know alot about bikes...they have changed since I was a kid. I'm really interested in identifying the frame manufacturer. Thanks again

Comment: I have checked to see if it was stolen, and tried to use the databases to find similar s/n's that would get me closer to a manufacturer,  but no luck. I have also contacted Python as the 1st two characters are "PY" but they have no record match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: The article is consistent with not caring for maintenance reasoning, however I am curious to know for nostalgia of saying what manufacturer it is. I may sell the bike later, much later. Nonetheless,  I agree that it is free to ask, and thought it a good post to intro the forum. I hope that referring to the article came with no intention of presenting ones self as pretentious, but rather an attempt at sharing insight.

Comment: It's not you, it's just that the main purpose of Stack Exchange is to be useless and hostile. And you can have a guess why many of are a bit annoyed at people who buy bikes with all identifying marks removed from sellers that can't explain the history of the bike.

Comment: Thanks. I like to simply have knowledge.  I hope the forum serves me well in the future. I can go to FB for useless and hostile.

Comment: What shocks are they, can't read the brand/model and don't recognize them.  What model are the Juicy brakes? Only really distinguishing frame feature I can see is the rear dropouts. Closest I can think is  probably early to mid 2000's (V Brake posts would have been gone from mid range frames by mid 2000's), mid range bike (LX components and Bontrager rims), may be newer but stem lengths started to shorten and  and head angle slacken from about mid 2000's

Comment: @mattnz What is midrange for you? My 2010 Merida with Deore XT has V-brakes (and also disc brake mounts).

Comment: Do you have a picture of the drive side? It looks an awful lot like an Orange Clockwork (mid 2000) and certainly the downtube added plate welding around the headtube is an Orange trait.

Comment: @Vladimir A common marketing trick is put a couple of XT components on an otherwise average bike and sell it for much more than the increased component cost. An XT equiped bike in 2010 with V brakes is one of these, or for a niche market

Comment: Rims and qr has a Bontrager logo on it - as I remember, Trek used (or uses?) those on their bike.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: "What shocks are they, can't read the brand/model and don't recognize them. What model are the Juicy brakes? "  They are Manitou Splice forks and Juicy 5 brakes.