# Does anyone know what make and model this bike is? Production year?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I found this bike while cleaning up a foreclosed home. I liked it and saved it from others taking it to the recycling center. Does anyone know what make, model and possibly year that it is?

[image: rusty bike]

Comment: The rear dropouts are very distinct, take a note of protrusions when looking for a match.

Comment: Looks like the Schwinn bikes of the 40's or 50's, the ones that were first adapted into mountain bikes and raced down the Repack.

Comment: It's an interesting bike. There were many makers of bikes this style over a long period of time. To have any hope of an accurate answer we need more information. Here is a link describing what information is needed for a solid identification - https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: Do see this link for why it's arguably unimportant what make and year. Also, that looks like a lot of rust on the surface. It's entirely possible the bike is extensively rusted inside its tubes. I'm loathe to waste stuff, but I doubt it's economical to restore the bike to operating condition. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is

Comment: Id like to see more detailed pics which could aid in discernment.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. I will post a couple more pictures. I'm glad I found this site and the wonderful people here.

Answer (score 3):

Without too much digging around I came across a 1950s Schwinn Corvette, although I don't think its a 100% identical bike it is i'm fairly sure a variant of the OPs.

[image: Seat]
[image: Rear Stay]
[image: Side View]
[image: Front Rack]

Pictures can also be found here [Just for image reference](https://www.realmiamivintage.com/product-page/original-1950s-schwinn-corvette-bicycle)

If anyone has time, a whole host of Schwinn catalogues can be found here [History Catalogues](https://bikehistory.org/catalogs/)

Comment: Its very close yes - but the rear-poiky bits of the dropouts are different.  Would help if OP had better photos, but this is a pretty good find.  Could simply be a couple of years different.

Comment: @Gaston I have already linked to that site in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the model name but it looks like [electra cruisers](https://www.electrabike.com/bikes/cruiser/cruiser-lux-7d).

[image]

Comment: This is not the bike in the original post. The bike in the original post is a complete bike. Steel frame, coaster brake single speed, forged steel one piece crank. The Electra pictured above is an aluminum frame, multi gear bike with hand brakes and a three piece crank. They both have a cantilever frame but they are very different.

Comment: The overall styling is similar, but there's at least 50 years between them if not more.  However the electra could have been inspired, or "drawn design features" from a bike like OPs.  Other than modern components and materials, the main difference is the angle of the seatstays.   Good spotting!

Comment: Thank you. I just think their appearance is looking like. Maybe it could be a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Those dropout shapes are very typical of bikes sold under the Murray and Sears names. I'm not sure who actually manufactured the frames, though. The extended dropout was on models made in the 60's to 80's time period.

You may be able to find a serial number on the left side dropout extension, such as the one shown here:
[image]

If the serial number is not there, it may be under the bottom bracket.
Here's a picture of the whole frame:
[image]

Comment: Usually serial numbers are useless. If it's a Murray, and if this thread is accurate https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/murray-serial-number-project.7014/ you can learn something about the bike from the serial number. Based on the poor pictures in the original post this is as good an answer as can be given.

Comment: @DavidD - I wouldn't say serial numbers are usually useless, as dedicated collectors have compiled serial number databases for many manufacturers, such as the one you linked. I would say, though, that serial numbers aren't always informative, and furthermore, one needs to have other clues about the manufacture in order to narrow down the serial number decoding possibilities.