# Help me identify this specific Giant XTC

Tags: identify-this-bike, giant

[image]I bought this bike a couple of years ago and I'm looking to sell it. I don't know what year it was, nor the frame size, but it's in really good shape. I pulled the serial number from the bottom of the frame but it hasn't helped me look up anything online.
Any extra information would be really appreciated
The guy I bought it from mentioned it being originally from Europe, possibly Germany if I remember right.
It's labeled XTC 1.5 performance series, but everything I looked up online shows either 1 or 2 as the options

Comment: Beyond it being a Giant Xtc, Model and age don't matter. The condition and specification of the componets (which may or may not be original) is what counts.

Comment: From what I can see (and it is hard to be totally sure) that frame style (lugged frame look) appears to be a 2004 model. Why not sell it as a 2004 Giant XtC 1.5? https://www.bikepedia.com/Quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2004&brand=Giant%20&model=XtC%201

Comment: Mid 2000s, nice bike.  When you do list it, please use a photo of the other side of the bike.  The drive train is important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with some generation of their ATX mountain bike.  The 890 ATX comes to mind. One aspect that will likely give us the best idea is those cool lugged frame accents where the top and down tubes meet the headtube.