# I need to find out what type of bike I have I just got it

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I need to find out what type of bike I have I just got it
[image]

Comment: Hi. Very cheap, ultralow value, if it works then fine for you!

Comment: Do you know the brand of the bike?

Comment: Have you asked from whoever you got it from?

Comment: It really does not make much sense to dig the exact brand of very cheap bikes. It does not really matter.

Comment: It's a department store bike.  Appears to be virtually unused, and should be a decent ride for someone who isn't too heavy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: I wonder why the decals were all removed, or possibly not installed.

Answer (score 8):

A Possible match and a caution.

**Possible Match**
It looks like a [NEXT Gauntlet](https://www.walmart.com/ip/24-NEXT-Girls-Gauntlet-Bike/55176013)  from Walmart.
[image]
They were made with both 24" and 26" wheels

**Caution**
In the picture your stem looks very high. Please check to make sure it's safe to ride.

On a handlebar stem there is usually a horizontal line stamped in the metal and the word "MAX" - or something like that.

The mark was put there so you would now how high you can raise your handlebar stem and still be safe. It should be inserted into the top of your fork far enough to cover the word horizontal line and the word "MAX".

If you can't see the horizontal line and the word MAX then you are OK.

If you can see it you need to use an Allen wrench (probably 6mm), loosen the stem bolt (you may need to tap it down with a hammer) and lower the stem so that the marks in the stem are covered by the top of the fork.

[image]

Comment: Great find - how did you go about working this out?

Comment: @Criggie I was working on a bike like this a few weeks ago. Walmart gives bikes that have been returned to a food pantry I work with. I fix the bikes, give them back to the pantry and they give them away. I searched each brand Walmart carries until I found this one.

Answer (score 2):

It is not important who made the bike. What is important is what parts it features.

Your bike has: a quill stem, spring-based full suspension, V-brakes, a padded wide saddle, kick stand, rear derailleur protector, spoke protector, non-quick-release axles. All are things typically put on supermarket-type bikes (sometimes called BSO). Cranks will probably be square-taper, the derailleurs are not visible.

It wil be sold by one of the big retail chains in your country or area - but you did not indicate where you live.

Comment: note: BSO does not stand for bullsh*t object, but it is almost as much derogatory, meaning Bike-Shaped Object.