# Can anybody help me identify my road bike frame?

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

[image][image: road bike]The serial number is located under the bottom bracket and its C0 30 402322. It was repainted and the fork is also been replaced. It has the downtube shifter mounts on it with braze on front mech hanger. The frame is made of aluminum and its has a standard 1" headset on it. The downtube is teardrop-like shaped as well.

Still trying to identify this frame for 2 years now and scoured the net for any info but no luck even my LBS who knew the painter and previous owner had no idea also cant find the previous owner to ask and the painter passed away.

Hope somebody can help. Thanks. Will add photos if somebody notices.

Comment: Welcome to the Bicycles SE site. There is no equivalent to an automobile VIN database on the cycling world. This is probably because bicycles are on average cheaper than cars, and they don’t require insurance to operate. Serial # alone is never sufficient to identify a bike of unknown brand without photos. In fact, serial # alone is completely worthless. Even with photos, the task can be hard.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good “ID My Bike” question?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question). Also be prepared for continued disappointment, and for being told that you [shouldn't care what make/model your bike is](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is).

Comment: Expanding on that - what difference would it make if you knew a brand name?  Its certainly interesting, but the bike is like a puppy from the pound - doesn't really care about its origin, it is here now to go for a ride.  And a name won't change that.    If you want a decal on the frame, get one made saying "ChadBike" which is as good as any other name.   This question will benefit from photos, add them with [edit] please.

Comment: Contrary to others'opinion, I think it is worthwhile to put the serial number: this way I personally feel I am not helping "someone" assessing the value of a stolen bike.

Can you add pictures? from the serial, there is a small chance it is a Schwinn roadbike.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Thanks for Welcoming me here!, yep it is quite hard to identify a frame that is quite old, rebranded and the original fork was replaced.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus read a lot about those "dont waste time in finding an answer" things, I'm probably just eager enough to continue.

Comment: @Criggie This actual frame was handed down to me by my late father and his name is still on it, we never had the time to talk about cycling because of his sudden death. The reason why I'm trying to identify the frame is so I can restore it to its original design as a tribute to him and I'm never gonna sell this frame as well.

Comment: @EarlGrey some older cyclist here says that its an old orbea model but it looks more like a panasonic order system. I hope it is a Schwinn but the geometry is a bit off.

Comment: sorry about the dark picture, I'm in a bit of a rush that day. I will upload a better one once I get a chance. Thank guys!.

Comment: @Chad another option is to try the registartion at https://www.orbea.com/nz-en/plates/info  (which will redirect to your nearest region)  Or to try their customer support directly at    ONLINE.ES@ORBEA.COM   You have the serial number already.

Comment: It’s hard to see clearly, but the components look like they’re from Shimano’s first generation of 10s road groups, e.g. Dura Ace 7800, Ultegra 6600. Chances are they’re perfectly functional as is, and may only need new cables, possibly a new chain. If you want to retain it for sentimental value alone, you arguably don’t need to restore anything unless it isn’t functioning. Heck, it would be perfectly rideable with new cables, if you want to ride as a tribute. If you want to improve the components but stick to the same era, search eBay for Dura Ace 7800.

Comment: If you wanted to restore the original paint, this could get expensive. That would require stripping the frame, and the painter would need to copy the original paint scheme from a catalog. Orbea may not keep copies of their historical catalogs. You might be able to get catalogs from the internet, and have someone copy one of the paint schemes in general. If you or your father appreciated Orbea’s Basque heritage, consider one of the orange paint schemes. It was the signature color of the Euskaltel Euskadi pro road team.

Comment: @Criggie I contacted orbea support a couple of days ago, unfortunately they cant find any info about it and recommended me to check their old bike catalogs online, the closes one I found is the ZEUS line of road bikes.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Its actually a Tiagra 4500 groupset, 52-39 crankset on 12-23 cassette, the logo got rubbed off due to shoe rub since my father used to race on it a lot. The cables are still in good condition though still smooth like new, the paint got some chips on it, downtube cable stops are a bit rusty and stuck on the frame, wheels are ksyrium elite 09 but the rear wheel aluminum nipples corroded and are bonded to the rim so I got them checked for repairs, luckily only 3 spokes needs replacing. Checked out the orbea catalog the Zeus line is a bit close. Man! those Euskaltel paintjob are awesome!

Comment: I doubt your dad would care about originality.   That you're still riding the same frame would make him happy.   Noone keeps a bike unchanged while owning and using it seriously, because parts wear and need replacing, and over time our bodies change - what once fitted fine eventually doesn't.   And you and he won't be the same body size/shape anyway so some adjustment will be needed.   If there's a race your dad used to enter, consider entering it yourself when C19 conditions allow for races again.

Comment: @Criggie If ever the frame breaks (I hope not) its a keeper, maybe hang it to a wall. The bad thing is I dont know if I will ever be able enough to race on it that much since I have a heart condition.

Comment: @Chad enter a race for completion rather than placing.  Getting to the end is what counts, along with having fun, and beating your previous time.

Comment: @Criggie Will do maybe after the pandemic, hope this pandemic ends faster than my possible race time LOL