# Can you help me identify the year of my specialized frame by serial number?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a Specialized Stumpjumper Sport. trying to figure out what year. Does anyone know how to identify by the serial number? I believe it is an 86 or 87.

Comment: Bicycle serial numbers don't work like automobile VINs. There is generally no way to get info about a bike from its serial number. The only exceptions are popular and collectable vintage bikes where someone has made a database of serial numbers. If you want a shot at bike identification here read [How do I ask a good “ID My Bike” question?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question).

Comment: Also consider [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Welcome to the bikes Stack Exchange. We don't mean to be cranky, but these questions are difficult to answer because there is no global equivalent of the Vehicle Identification Numbers we see in cars. There is usually no way to tell a bike's identity from just the serial number. Even if you provide photographs as recommended in the thread Argenti linked, these questions are frequently difficult. The link Jeff provided in the answer, as well as the one I added in a comment there, might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Here's the 1986 version of the Stumpjumper]!

Above picture is the 1986 version of the Stumpjumper

And here is a link that may help you research the exact year of your vintage Stumpjumper: [Vintage Mountain Bike Workshop](http://www.vintagemtbworkshop.com/1986-specialized-stumpjumper.html)

Comment: Also, the Museum of Mountain Bike Art & Technology maintains manufacturer specifications, including the stock components and a brief description of the paint scheme, for older Specialized bikes. It might be worth a look also, but keep in mind stock components might change or the bike might even have been repainted: http://mombatbicycles.com/Specialized_Specs.htm

Comment: @Weiwen Ng Thanks for the reference! I run across many older mountain bikes people bring to me for repair or just to ask about. The vast majority are nothing special, but some bear looking into...especially the models of my youth in the 80's.