# Does anyone know what model/approximate year this Giant bike is?

Tags: identify-this-bike, hybrid-bike, giant

Does anyone know the model and approximate year of this Giant bike? Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: light grey-brown 3x bike with v-brakes and a fat cruiser-type saddle. The handlebars look very odd, but are not clear in the picture.]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Is there anything else you can tell us about the bike?  How long you've had, for instance?  Also, you might want to check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is

Comment: Also some close-ups might be useful, as well as the names of any of the components, like the cranks, brakes and rear derailleur.  Is the bike modified?  The handlebars look exceedingly odd.

Comment: Thanks, DavidW! I didn't realize I could add more than one photo. I'm looking to potentially purchase it and the seller said he didn't know the model or year. Probably not a great option given those responses, but figured I'd inquire!

Comment: @EricaMallon frankly the year and model is far less important than the bike's overall condition.  If its been maintained then it could be "like new" vs left outside in the rain.  Other than the bottle cage, it looks completely original which may indicate minimal use.  And remember if you don't like it, you can sell it on later for about whatever you paid for it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks a lot like a [2011 Giant Cypress ST](https://www.bikepedia.com/Quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2011&brand=Giant%20&model=Cypress%20ST)

[image]

Giant used this frame with a variety of components over several years.
I tried to match components and graphics to the correct year

This bike falls into the "comfort" bike category. Giant still makes a bike with the "Cypress" label but the frame is different.