# Red bike frame BMX don't know what it is

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a red bmx bike with flat plates on both sides in the front it has circles through them I don't know what kind of bike it is it's just the frame I bought from a friend he said he thought it was a diamond back but I never seen one of them made like this one can anyone help me out. Thanks

1. [image: List item]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You should check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is as it may help you figure out what you _need_ to know and how to ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks a lot like a bike made by Giant branded in different ways for different markets.

There are several frames made with a circle cutout and a sort of X shaped gusset. The circle in the middle with a rolled edge is rare.

Here it is as a [1983/1984 Repco Team Hotfoot](http://www.bloggingadeadhorse.com/hotfoot6.php)
It was [made by Giant for Repco](http://www.bloggingadeadhorse.com/giant.php)
[image]
[bloggingadeadhorse.com](http://www.bloggingadeadhorse.com/hotfoot6.php)

Here's an 82 Team Giant with a similar frame
[image]

Here is a [1981 Giant GMX-250](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/giant_bicycles/72936) with a similar frame
[image]
[bmxmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/giant_bicycles/72936)