# Can someone help me figure out the identity of my bike here is the logo

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

Hi i bought this bike a while back because it was so light and rides so smooth. Just wondering if anyone knows who made it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  If it's really important to you to know the make ([even if you don't really need to](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)) then more pictures would be helpful; right now it will only be recognized if someone happens to remember the logo.

Comment: Later question about identifying the whole frame:   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/79515/bike-frame-identification-for-my-giant-bike

Comment: @kerrdog211 Also, it would help if you "accept" the answer below by clicking the little tick/check mark to the left, just below the vote arrows.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

That is the emblem of Giant Bicycles - one of the biggest bike manufacturers in the world

Comment: Side note, Giant makes bikes under its own name, and their factories do contract manufacturing for many other prominent bicycle brands. This is a common arrangement in many industries. This is due in part to labor costs, although the wage differentials are shrinking, as well as just due to concentration of manufacturing expertise.