# Bike frame identification for my giant bike

Tags: road-bike

I have had this bike for a while and love it. I have been told it is a Giant brand bike but I have no Clue what type it is. I wanted to get the original parts for it. Someone had painted it black and I can not find any numbers on it. Just the Giant logo.[image]

Comment: At first glance I'd say its a mongrel - a bitser bike made from different sources.   The fork look too long for the bike and the handlebars are a different style.   Can you talk to whoever you got the bike from originally ?

Comment: Actually, a month ago you asked about the logo on the head tube, here on SE.  The question is https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77564/can-someone-help-me-figure-out-the-identity-of-my-bike-here-is-the-logo linking here for relevance.   This is a subtly different question, though related.

Answer (score 1):

The frame has some distinctive features, like the bottom bracket location and the connection top tube - seat tube.

After a quick search on the internet for images of "giant bicycle cruiser urban" and "giant bicycle" I was lucky enough to strike this picture:
[image]

which indicates your bicycle is a [Giant Suede](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/94349/). The year may vary.

Nice bike, I am glad you are enjoying it.

BUT

for peace of mind I would recommend you to have a look for the serial number if the bike is [being missed by someone](https://bikeindex.org/bikes?stolenness=all) (I am not accusing you or who gave the bike of any crime, it could have been painted for thousands of reasons, c'est la vie, I am just a bit worried about the owner missing what it seems a great bike).

Comment: Awesome find!  Looks like even the saddle might be original, and the only things that have changed are the loss of the chain case, and the missing front brake.