# Need help identifying year of my bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

SN# 7124865
Norco Bush Pilot Mountain Bike

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Serial numbers are only relevant to the manufacturer.  The manufacturing year is not relevant in most cases. You’ll be able to buy anything you need to make it rideable again. See  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is

Comment: Can't help you sorry.  We might make an educated guess if you added a photo of your bike.

Comment: https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?item=90974

Answer (score 0):

You can check on Norco website. They have all models by year. You can use the paint color and part's name to find the one that match your bike.