# I have a Monterey Marie with the serial number k70 38 319, can anybody help identify the year this was manufactured? By

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a Monterrey Murray with the serial number k70 38 319, can anybody help identify the year this was manufactured?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Pictures would help a great deal.  Note, however, that [there aren't really all that many cases](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is) when you actually need to know the year of manufacture of a bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [forum post](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/murray-serial-number-project.7014/) serial numbers beginning with "K" indicate 1954

> I don't know how far back this goes , but I know that Murray used a single letter to represent the year since at least 1949. Most of these bikes up until the early 60's had the serial number stamped on the bottom of the bottom bracket. I have seen the letters MOS stamped on most of these. I ASSUME that they stand for Murray of Ohio Supply. This is usually followed by a - and a single letter. That letter will be the year code. After the year code will be a 2 or 3 digit number that stands for the model number. This excludes bikes built for Sears and Gambles(Hiawatha). Sears bikes had a 502 and Gambles bikes had a WG or a WG and a single digit. Sears bikes then had a 2 - 5 digit number afterwards that stood as the model number and was actually used in there catalogs as the part number. Gambles Hiawathas were the same way.
>
> F = 49
> G = 50
> H = 51
> I = 52
> J = 53
> K = 54
> L = 55
> M = 56
> N = 57
> P = 58
> R = 59
> S = 60
> T = 61
> U = 62
> W = 63
> X = 64
> Y = 65
>
> In 65 they were changing there serial number style and by then they were on the left rear dropout. Some 65 bikes had an MO5 which stood for Murray of Ohio 1965. After these 3 digits was a 2 or 3 digit model number followed by and X and a 1 or 2 digit number that I will discuss momentarily.
> MO5 = 65
> MO6 = 66
> MO7 = 67
> MO8 = 68
> In 69, they changed the layout yet again. They dropped the O. They also went to a 4 digit model number.
> M9 = 69
> M0 = 70
> and so on.