# What year, make , and model is this bike frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

The link, best as I can extract it:  https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPqwbpMKmSm-noaaUrWOg9vwT-NsmKlunFvknVfCcUNY7eJGKzgFoK3ShSC06o2dw?pli=1&key=dTNWYlFiVHJUenFNVHpZVEJQbkxRaG40ZGJsZFhB

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: If you read that and you still want to know, you will need to provide more informative photos at a minimum. Review this answer, but do realize that if you provide photos that show head badges or decals, those still do not guarantee an answer. https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337

Answer (score 5):

1966 Murray Wildcat Deluxe frame

https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/1969-schwinn-sting-ray-fastback-1973-schwinn-speedster-20-1966-murray-wildcat-deluxe.45269/

[image: ""]

Comment: Very similar but not identical, could be a different year.  The chain case above is more squared off at the front and pointier at the rear,   Maybe the angle, but the lower top-tube  pictured seems to taper at the front as well.   Still its in the right ballpark, so +1 for the find.

Comment: ah, @Criggie, I think your concerns are misguided. The year could be any in a decade but the rear dropouts are unique to Murray. The chaincase on Jay's bike is from a schwinn. I'm totally just doing this one for the points, but there is solid info here for Jay to work with to finish his research..