# Nervex Lugged steel frame identification

Tags: road-bike, campagnolo

I bought this old frame recently and have stripped it down. I am trying to identify the frame maker/brand if possible. Please see photos below of the parts and frame junctions. Info relating to dimensions also follows - thanks for your help!
Rear mech: Zeus Gransport 2 - 5 Speed
Front mech: Campag ?
Crankset: Magistroni
Brakes: Weinmann Type 730
Rims look like Weinmann High pressure
English threaded BB - Nervex followed by lug set numbers. then stamped over the top W 6924
The rear dropout appears to have the letters "BRE" stamped
I have more photos also
Seat tube ID / OD: 26.6 / 28.6, CTT: 560mm
Head tube ID / OD: 29.8 / 31.6
Top tube OD: 25.6, CTC: 575mm
Frame weighs: 1937g
Fork weighs 910g
[image]

Comment: You might want to check out the answers to https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that this is impossible to identify as-is.

The blue paint is not original and looks in poor condition so you could gently sand back through the paint layers on the downtube and headtube to see if you can expose branding and decals.

The assembled bike is a bit of a hodge-podge with some of the frame braze ons, eg for rear brake, left unused. I wouldn't trust that any of the parts are original when the bike is in this condition.

It is not a pure race frame either -- note eyelets for mudguards -- but could still be good quality tubing.