# Please help me find the make and model

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

[image: silver-painted frame]
[image: hand-traced serial numbers]

Hello, so I believe I have narrowed the make down to either a Marin frame, or an Orange frame but I've been wrong before, so any information anyone can give me on either how to find out the make and model or straight up if you know off-hand. I have looked for hours at bike frames from many different years with no success.

Thank you in advance.

The serial number reads like this:
7DMPPNMD
216867TB04491

Comment: First reapply all the paint and labels and badges.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Please don't SHOUT AT US; it's considered courteous to use normal text casing (capitalize only the first word of sentences and names, except for trademarks).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 5):

That bike has some features that make it stand out. It's a single pivot, the shock mounts to a truss between the top tube and down tube, it's a linkage driven and the (missing) linkage attaches to the top tube. The curve to the top tube is quite unique too.

It appears you have a Cannondale Perp, circa 2007-2009.

Some quick research show it shares some parts with the Judge, like the derailleur hanger.

Between the missing hanger and brake dropout you are talking major money to restore. The missing linkage and associated bushings etc is a major issue unless you have them in a box somewhere. I assume finding a compatible shock isn't a huge deal. Jordan "Boostmaster" Olthuis has been able to find shock for his old Norco Shore and it's probably a similar size required.

Luckily Cannondate still has the [manual](https://www.cannondale.com/-/media/files/manual-uploads/manuals/2007_perp_owners_manual_supplement_en.pdf) available if you want to find the part numbers.

If this model bike is nostalgic to you, you can likely find a complete bike much cheaper than finding parts for this frame (again, assuming the linkage and dropouts are missing). You would have an easier time sourcing parts for a more collectible brand and model bike if you are into vintage downhill bikes.

Here is a pic of the 2008 model taken from the [2008 Cannondale catalogue](https://www.cannondale.com/-/media/files/manual-uploads/manuals/us_catalog_2008.pdf) (also available on Cannondale's website):
[image]

Comment: Excellent find!  Have a bounty for that.

Comment: OMG ! wow, thankyou so much? It must have taken you a little bit of time for you to find that information ??? You have no idea how very appreciative i am. Thankyou so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I like bikes, so figuring out the era was easy. The fact it was Cannondale did throw me off as I'm not too familiar with them from that era, but it definitely looks like a freeride bike (not quite a DH). It's not a Norco Shore, RM Slayer or Spesh SX. It's definitely not a Kona from that era. Just a process of elimination.