# What brand is this bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

I bought bike from friend and cant figure out the actual brand it has chromoly stickers on it all high end parts from what i can see. Its a 8 speed. Has Serial Number bh2011063348[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Not that it's relevant, but the bike pictured shares many elements with my beater from the 80s. With the details provided, it may as well be from the same factory. Bicycle parts are (usually) generic and easily interchangeable/upgradeable, and bike manufacturers are a dime a dozen. Unless there are any markings on the frame or any components that are manufacturer-specific, you're out of luck. If it's a common frame in your area, chances are a LBS would be able to help you out. Otherwise, the link that shoover suggests is your answer.

Comment: [How do I ask a good "ID My Bike" question](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question)