# Help me identify this norco bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I would appreciate if someone could help me identify this bike? I can't seem to find the serial number I'm the usual spots!

[image: black Norco bike]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: The side of the downtube says "Fluid" and that's a Norco model.   https://www.norco.com/bikes/mountain/trail/fluid-fs/   What else is written on the labels?

Answer (score 2):

Detailed pictures of the right/drivetrain side would definitely help but from what we can see and read on the picture, it is a *Norco Fluid FS 3* of an unknown year, but definitely earlier than the 21-23 models still visible on their product [page](https://www.norco.com/bikes/mountain/trail/fluid-fs/).

I was using this [site](https://99spokes.com/en-EU/bikes?makerId=norco&q=fluid%20fs%203&suspension=full) to compare it against previous generations of the Fluid. Looks like it is older than the oldest model shown there (2018). The sloped top tube only occurs on older models.

Some other observations

- I'm no MTB expert but all the newer models I have seen have a 1x 30t crankset, your bike obviously has 2x crankset including a clamped/band-on front-derailleur. This might not mean that it has been retro-fitted but might just be indicative that the bike was made before ~2015 when Shimano introduced 1x in XTR (if it is a Shimano groupset but the rotors look like that)
- Also, the Kenda tires fitted might not be original and seem to have a lighter tread pattern than tires usually fitted to fully MTBs (at least looking at Norco's Fluid models)

So my guess is that you have a Fluid FS 3 from the early 2010s and some modifications were made to ride it on a daily basis or on easier terrain.

Comment: FYI 1x was not generalised in the early 2010's for MTBs, Shimano didn't even have a 1x groupset then (but SRAM probably did, they were first on the market, but I don't know when).

Comment: You are right, that's probably just indicative of a bike made before 1x11 groupsets were available (ca. 2014 for XTR M9000, for example) or at least common in MTB builds, I adapted the statement. It's probably just a early 2010s MTB of the type and that's a good as it gets with one photo on the internet and a free-of-charge community service. ;)